# What is the probability that a contestant is a guitarist? The events are independent?

Tags: probability

$50$ pianists, $30$ violinists, and $20$ guitarists take part in a music competition. 
 
$10\%$ of the pianists, $33\%$ of the violinists, and $10\%$ of the guitarists attend this contest for the first time. 
a) Select at random a contestant who attends the competition for the first time.  
 Show that the probability that this contestant is a guitarist is (approximately) $0.118$. 
b) Consider the events “the contestant is a guitarist” and “the contestant attends the competition for the first time”, are these events independent?

Solve:

a) This what I did: I think that I have to calculate the probability that the contestant is a guitarist given that he partecipate to the competition the first time,
; $P(G|F)=\frac{P(G\cap F)}{P(F)}=\frac{0.1}{0.169}=0.59$. Considering $P(F)=\frac{0.1*50+0.33*30+0.1*20}{100}=0.169$ the percentage that a contestant is going for the first time, $P(G)=\frac{20}{50+30+20}=0.2$ the probability that a contestant is a guitarist, and $P(G\cap F)=\frac{0.1*20}{20}=0.1$ the probability of the intersection of the guitarists than are going for the first time. The result is quite different from the answer, where I'm wrong?

b) If two events are independent we know that: $P(G\cap F)=P(G)*P(F)=0.2*0.169=0.0338\neq0.1$. So in my opinion the two events are dependent, right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For $a$, did you mean $.188$?

Comment: "30  violinists"..."33 of the violinists"????

Comment: @JohnDourma yes, it should be the correct probability

Comment: @DavidG.Stork sorry, I forgot the %, now it is correct! :)

Comment: In $P(G)$ you calculate the probability that a contestant is a pianist, not a guitarist

Comment: @user289143 you are right, corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(G \cap F)=0.02$ since there a $2$ guitarists attending for the first time out of $100$ contestants.

$P(F)= \frac{0.1 \cdot 50 + 0.33 \cdot 30 + 0.1 \cdot 20}{100} \sim 0.17$

$P(G|F)=\frac{P(G \cap F)}{P(F)}=\frac{0.02}{0.17} \sim 0.118$

For part b) $P(G) \cdot P(F)=0.2 \cdot 0.17=0.034 \neq 0.02 = P(G \cap F)$ , hence the events are dependent

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now it's clear :)